# Unir Array bidimensional

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente array

```
array 
  0 => 
    array 
      'codigo' =>  '10' 
      'nombre' =>  'jonh' 
      'color' =>  'green' 
  1 => 
    array 
      'codigo' =>  '20' 
      'nombre' =>  'pitter' 
      'color' =>  'blue' 
  2 => 
    array 
      'codigo' => '10' 
      'nombre' => 'lucas' 
      'color' =>  'blue' 
  3 => 
    array 
      'codigo' =>  '20' 
      'nombre' => 'louis' 
      'color' =>  'blue' 

  4 => 
    array 
      'codigo' =>  '30' 
      'nombre' => 'patrick' 
      'color' =>  'yellow'
```

es posible unir en un array los elementos que sean del mismo código donde quede el nombre con su respectivo color y así con cada uno de ellos?

tomando en cuenta que el array se genera a partir de una consulta a la base de datos y pueden venir n cantidad de array anidados.

que quede algo como por ejemplo

```
array

0=> 'codigo'='10'

      array 0=>
      'nombre' => lucas
      'color' => blue
      array 1=>
      'nombre' => john
      'color' => green

1=> 'codigo'='20'

      array 0=>
      'nombre' => lois
      'color' => blue
      array 1=>
      'nombre' => pitter
      'color' => blue

2=> 'codigo'='30'

      array 0=>
      'nombre' => patrick
      'color' => yellow
```

algo así que una los códigos iguales

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Pregunto ¿qué es lo que quieres? Pon un ejemplo del resultado esperado pulsando en [edit]. Gracias.

Comment: ya coloque un ejemplo de lo que quiero. gracias

Comment: Para lo que quieres deberás recorrer los arrays, de forma recursiva y crear otros nuevos con la estructura que necesitas, o quizá sea posible obtenerlos reformulando las consultas SQL. Cuanta más información de lo que tienes añadas más fácil es obtener ayuda.

Comment: podrías dar un ejemplo de como recorrerlo en forma recursiva?? gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que algo como esto te puede servir.

Suponiendo que `$mArray` es tu array original, vamos a crear un `$arrCodes` que agrupará en un índice todos los `codigo` repetidos, guardando los sub-arrays para los datos `nombre` y `color`.

```
$arrCodes = array();
foreach($mArray as $subArray) {
    $arrCodes[$subArray['codigo']][] = array_diff_key($subArray, array_flip((array) ['codigo']));
}
```

El resultado final se parecerá a esto:

print_r($arrCodes);

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nombre] => jonh
                    [color] => green
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [nombre] => lucas
                    [color] => blue
                )

        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nombre] => pitter
                    [color] => blue
                )

        )

)
```

Y la lectura se podría hacer así:

```
$outPut="";
foreach ($arrCodes as $codigo=>$arrData){
    $outPut.="Código: $codigo\n";
    foreach ($arrData as $data){
        $outPut.="\t$data[nombre] - $data[color]\n";
    }
}
echo $outPut;
```

**Salida:**

```
Código: 10
    jonh - green
    lucas - blue
Código: 20
    pitter - blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Con una función recursiva podría ser así (aunque no tiene mucho sentido en este caso):

```
<?php

$arrayAgrupado = array();

function agruparCodigos($array, &$arrayAgrupado) {
    $elemento = current($array);

    if($elemento !== false) {
        $llave = "codigo " . $elemento['codigo'];

        $arrayAgrupado[$llave][] = array_diff_key($elemento, ['codigo' => 0]);

        next($array);

        agruparCodigos($array, $arrayAgrupado);
    }
}

agruparCodigos($array, $arrayAgrupado);

?>
```

Resultado ($arrayAgrupado):

```
Array (
    ["codigo 10"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ["nombre"] => jonh
                    ["color"] => green
                ),

            [1] => Array
                (
                    ["nombre"] => lucas
                    ["color"] => blue
                ),
        ),

    ["codigo 20"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ["nombre"] => pitter
                    ["color"] => blue
                ),

            [1] => Array
                (
                    ["nombre"] => louis
                    ["color"] => blue
                ),
        ),

    ["codigo 30"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ["nombre"] => patrick
                    ["color"] => yellow
                )
        )
)
```